# Mysql UPDATE (from PHP) - only runs first few rows.. Alls CELL locked after one UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I run a MYSQL UPDATE from PHP. It produces output, which is shown in the browser - No probz.
The mysql db updates various number of rows.. If i try 10 rows, it produces first 5 rows. If i try 4 it produces first and last.
I started making INSERT for all rows, and it inserted 1000+ rows in few seconds for this excact same database. The UPDATE seems to be way off in some way...
Maybe people have some inputs to why this could happend ?

The main concern, is that after i have produced updates on the rows, the rows are "locked" for updates through PHP. This in my mind is really a weird point and i don't get what is going on. I can offcourse make updates through the phpMYadmin.

CODE as requested:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE `search` SET `pr_image` = '$primage', `pr_link` = '$pr_link' WHERE `s_id` = '$id' ");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us the code for the update query.

Comment: You have a `,` right before `WHERE` clause.. can you try it without that `,` please?

Comment: That was a typing fault(also corrected).. it ain't actually in the code.

Comment: is 's_id' primary key? check whether it duplicated by newly added id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `search` SET `pr_image` = $primage, `pr_link` = $pr_link WHERE `s_id` = $id
```

Try with this query.

Comment: I was having fields with ** '  ** in them, and now i use str_replace to kill this.. the above code which i was working is working, but the previuos input killed the

Comment: OK, so i redid the thing.. and used mysql_real_escape_string instead of the replace.. i accept your answer, and you were some kind of giving me the hint to what i was missing / doing.. Thanks